# What is the tension member in IEC 61000-6-8:2020 Table 6?

Tags: emc, optics, fiber

In IEC 61000-6-8:2020 3.1.10, an optical fiber port is defined as port at which an optical fiber is connected to an equipment. In Table 6 – Requirements for conducted emissions, other wires ports, it defines four kinds of test ports:

1. Wired network ports (3.1.18)
2. Optical fibre ports (3.1.10) with metallic shield or tension members
3. Broadcast receiver tuner ports (3.1.2)
4. Antenna ports (3.1.1)

I want to know what the "tension member" is in item No.2. Does it refer to a structure of the optical fiber port or a part of optical fiber? If it related to optical fiber, does "tension member" equal to metallic “strength member," located in the core of fiber optics, which could make the fiber supporting for example in outside installation on poles? [Does "optical fiber with metallic shield" mean armored fiber cable?](https://community.fs.com/blog/what-is-armored-fiber-optic-cable.html)

https://www.thefoa.org/tech/ref/basic/Armor.jpg

Figure No.1 I drafted a drawing of my understanding, is it right?

[image: Figure No.1 I drafted a drawing of my understanding, is it right?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tension Member (also called the Strength Member) within a cable assembly basically just provides added strength to the cable. For example when running the cable through a barrier you would pull directly on the tension member material not the optical fibers. If the cable is freely hung the tension member material supports or takes up the "tension". In both cases the tension member prevents damage and or stretching of the more delicate fiber optic material.

The tension member can be made of wire but can also be made of other materials such as woven polymers or fiberglass. It can be positioned at the center, to one side, or even straddling both sides of the data fibers. In some cases the data carrying fibers would be fully encased in a metal fiber jacket (cladding or metallic shielding) which would be considered the strength member.

The same method of protection can be used for standard electrical cabling that contain multiple fine wires that might be damaged due to excessive tension.

Answer (score 1):

In IEC 61000-6-8:2020 Table 6 – Requirements for conducted emissions, other wires ports, it defines 4 kinds of test ports need to do a CE test. One of them is "Optical fiber ports with metallic shield or tension members".

The rational is some kind of fiber cables has metallic armor, either loose-buffered or tight-buffered with metallic central tension member(also called strength member). These long metal wires could conduct RF noise via EUT's optical port.

The picture shown below is the said "metallic shield or tension member".
[image: Figure No.1 metallic shield or tension member]

Comment: If a metallic tension member were electrically connected at both ends there could be an issue of conducted emissions. However if the tension member is only meant for mechanical support then there may not even be a reason for an electrical connection at both ends. You'd need to verify if there is such a requirement.